# Ensuring no unintended leaking before authentication

Tags: authentication, pbkdf-2

Assume my authentication system consists of querying an endpoint to get sign in parameters `cost` and `salt`, `auth_hash`.

After receiving these parameters, I will use `cost` and `salt` to derive a 768 bit key using PBKDF2:

```
key = pbkdf2(user_password, salt, cost, 768).hex
```

I then split the key three ways:

```
server_password = key.first_third
encryption_key = key.second_third
auth_key = key.third_third
```

I will then use `auth_key` to authenticate the parameters sent from the server and make sure the computed authentication hash matches the incoming `auth_hash`:

```
local_auth_hash = HMAC(cost.to_string + salt, auth_key)
abort if local_auth_hash != auth_hash
```

Now, during normal app flow, I will encrypt user data with `encryption_key` and authenticate it with `auth_key`.

My question is, is it safe to use `auth_key` in both of these contexts (sign in and data encryption)? The reason I would suspect that it might not be ok is that the server can return any cost and salt, and have me authenticate it with my `auth_key`, and potentially try to glean information this way.

Comment: Note that querying large amounts (ie larger than the PRF's output bit-length $h$) of keying material directly from PBKDF2 is a bad idea. The reason is that it will essentially compute the first $h$ bits using `cost` operations and then compute the second $h$ bits using `cost` operations. So an attacker can probably just compute the first part of the key to verify his guesses while your user has to compute 2*cost operations. The fix is to use PBKDF2 to output $h$ bits of keying material and then run PBKDF2 with _1_ iteration on the result to expand  it.

Comment: Maybe we should make up a hashtag for this kind of question: #whynotTLS?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my comments in no particular order:

1. Don't create your own crypto.
2. We don't analyze designs on this website because it is hard work and you shouldn't create your own anyway.
3. It seems that for this protocol to work the server will have to store the user password in plaintext. That seems like a bad idea.
4. Using this scheme will allow an attacker to brute force the user password using only the information that has been transmitted since he can validate

   `auth_key = PBKDF2(password_guess, salt, cost, 768))`

   `HMAC(cost.to_string + salt, auth_key) == auth_hash`. That also seems like a bad idea.